# IAR Embedded Workbench won't compile

Tags: embedded, workbench, iar, interfacing

I use IAR embedded workbench for my interfacing class and I can't compile even a simple `C` code. It aborts with the error:

```
Internal Error: [CoreUtil/General]: Unexpected windows exception (0xe06d7363) at 752EC41F 
Error while running C/C++ Compiler
```

Comment: `0xe06d7363` sounds like an uncaught exception, which may be a sign of pretty much any problem (access problems/missing files/...)

Comment: i re-installed it to check nothing was wrong with the installation

Comment: The question is probably "off topic" since it is not directly about programming - one for IAR support perhaps.  However some general advice: Try running the compiler from the command line rather from within WorkBench (just to isolate the probem to the compiler).  You might post the complete build-log if you can since that will show how the compiler was invoked. You should probably ensure that WorkBench was installed and is run with Admin rights.  Try a different PC perhaps or a Virtual Machine, with a different version of Windows installed.

Comment: you should report this to the IAR support. Make sure that you have a minimal code example that triggers the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I installed a newer version and it is working now. The previous version was v5.5. I installed v6.0 and it is working now. I still don't know what was wrong with the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and re-installing the same version as an admin did the trick for me.